# Best solution SurfaceView vs View drawing?

Tags: android

I would like to display the score when user click on a button (make +1 fly to top of the screen) and I wonder if it is better to use a surfaceview or view?

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) for more information on the differences between `SurfaceView` and `View`.

For your case, `View` would probably be simpler and appropriate.

> If your application does not require a significant amount of processing or frame-rate speed (perhaps for a chess game, a snake game, or another slowly-animated application), then you should consider creating a custom View component and drawing with a Canvas in View.onDraw(). The most convenient aspect of doing so is that the Android framework will provide you with a pre-defined Canvas to which you will place your drawing calls.

A `SurfaceView`, on the other hand, is not drawn on the main thread and instead takes place on a secondary thread:

> The SurfaceView is a special subclass of View that offers a dedicated drawing surface within the View hierarchy. The aim is to offer this drawing surface to an application's secondary thread, so that the application isn't required to wait until the system's View hierarchy is ready to draw. Instead, a secondary thread that has reference to a SurfaceView can draw to its own Canvas at its own pace.

Answer (score 0):

I think view fits this scenario better. You could translate a view to the top of the screen.

So far, I've only used SurfaceView for rendering background graphics. Of course you could do it using SurfaceView, but that would bring more complexity in terms of coding. You need to draw this "+1" and calculate its position from frame to frame.

Using a View, you could just apply an animation, set the duration, and that should do the trick.